# EditText not scrolling into view after first time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I got my layout working as i want, except that when the EditText view is behind the soft keyboard, it is not being scrolled to the visible area of the screen.

Instead, if part of the EditText was in the visible area of the screen, it gets clipped or if it was completely behind the area now covered by the keyboard, and it remains invisible.

I am creating the Layout dynamically, the first time it gets created it looks like this:

[image]

For the first time, when i focus an EditText view, the EditText gets scrolled into view correctly, like this:

[image]

If i close this Layout, and i come back later, and then i focus the same EditText view, instead of being scrolled into view, it gets clipped like this:

[image]

Notice how the picture at the top doesn't get scrolled, and the EditText views get clipped to fit the layout. Any ideas why this happens? I am sure it is something simple, like how i am "destroying" the layout object.

I am creating the layout like this:

```
rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
rl.setId(5000);
```

I am "deleting" the layout like this:

```
 rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I will appreciate your input.

Comment: Using setVisibility to View.GONE, you are not actually destroying the view. It still remains there. And if you are adding more views later or following to add the same view again and again, then it will lead to these scenario.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, i suspected that. I will make some tests and follow up.

Comment: Ok @Brian, let me know if my suggestion worked for you.

Comment: Yup! That was it, thank you VERY much! :)

Comment: Anytime man. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidManifest.xml add in your activity the feature below:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```